# Add a header on operations using a given service in OpenAPI contract

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, swashbuckle

A ASP.NET Core application has two services :

```cs
public interface IPrimaryService { }
public class PrimaryService : IPrimaryService { }

public interface ISecondaryService { }
public class SecondaryService : ISecondaryService
{
    public SecondaryService(IPrimaryService service) {}
}
```

That is used in the controller :

```cs
[Route("foo")]
public class FooController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("primary")]
    public IActionResult Primary([FromServices] IPrimaryService primary) => Ok();
    [HttpGet("secondary")]
    public IActionResult Secondary([FromServices] ISecondaryService secondary) => Ok();
}
```

The primary service need a specific header to work, then the Open API contract must state this information.

I try to write a custom `IOperationFilter` to automatically detect all operations that need the `IPrimaryService` and add the specific header in the Open API contract :

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddTransient<IPrimaryService, PrimaryService>();
    services.AddTransient<ISecondaryService, SecondaryService>();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebApplication1", Version = "v1" });
        c.OperationFilter<AddPrimaryHeadersOperationFilter>();
    });
}
```

This is my try :

```cs
public class AddPrimaryHeadersOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    IServiceProvider _provider;
    public AddPrimaryHeadersOperationFilter(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }

    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (NeedPrimaryService(context.MethodInfo))
        {
            if (operation.Parameters == null)
                operation.Parameters = new List<OpenApiParameter>();
            operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter {
                Name = "Primary-Id",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Required = false,
                Schema = new OpenApiSchema { Type = "int" }
            });
        }
    }

    private bool NeedPrimaryService(MethodInfo action)
    {
        foreach (var prm in action.GetParameters())
        {
            if (NeedPrimaryService(prm.ParameterType))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private bool NeedPrimaryService(Type service)
    {
        if (service == typeof(IPrimaryService))
        {
            return true;
        }
        //Try to get the implementation TYPE of the service
        object implementation = _provider... 
        return false;
    }
}
```

This work to detect the action where `IPrimaryService` is directly injected, but this don't work if `IPrimaryService` is injected through another service (in the example `ISecondaryService`).

Naively I think I have to go through the dependency tree, but I don't know how.

Any idea is welcome.

PS : PrimaryService is scoped, because it need the request's header.

PS : I know this don't detect if the service is got from a factory method, but in my case is acceptable.

PS : It explore also the controller, but I removed this part to shorten the question. Idem to check if the action's parameter has the attribute `FromServices`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `private bool NeedPrimaryService(Type service)`, you can use something like this.

```
var constructorInfos = service.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public);
foreach (var item in constructorInfos)
{
    var paramsInfo = item.GetParameters();
    foreach (var singleParam in paramsInfo)
    {
        if (singleParam.ParameterType == typeof(IPrimaryService))
        {
            return true; // or do some other useful things...
        }
    }
}
```

I just blindly typing these out to describe the idea... optimize to fit your use case please :D

**UPDATE**

Let me make this a bit more clearer... on your `private bool NeedPrimaryService(Type service)` method, you evaluate all the parameters from what got inject to action endpoint (through a loop from `NeedPrimaryService`).

so... this should detect the service:

```
// This method is responsible for evaluating all params for each Action endpoint
private bool NeedPrimaryService(Type service)
    {
        if (service == typeof(ISecondaryService))
        {
            return true;
        }
        // I know this only detect one level depth of ISecondaryService, write a recursive somewhere and use it as needed
        if(service.IsInterface)
        {
                var properties = test.GetProperties();
                foreach (var item in properties)
                {
                    if(item.GetType() == typeof(ISecondaryService)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
        }
        else // Check service.IsClass make sure the rest params would be struct or primitive data... but feel free with those type checking later, I'm aiming just express the idea
        {
                var constructorInfos = service.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public);
                foreach (var item in constructorInfos)
                {
                    var paramsInfo = item.GetParameters();
                    foreach (var singleParam in paramsInfo)
                    {
                        if (singleParam.ParameterType == typeof(ISecondaryService))
                        {
                            return true; // or do some other useful things...
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: This don't work if `service` is `ISecondaryService` because the interface don't have constructor. The problem is to retrieve the service implementation from the injected interface.

Comment: @vernou I updated the answer to clearer the solution a bit, make a recursive to evaluate as deep as you want... time to smash that accepted button dude